# Piecewise step function for changing dollar amounts?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, economics

Visiting the Wikipedia article for [continuous functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuous_function) I found this:

> As an example, consider the function h(t), which describes the height
>   of a growing flower at time t. This function is continuous. By
>   contrast, if M(t) denotes the amount of money in a bank account at
>   time t, then the function jumps at each point in time when money is
>   deposited or withdrawn, so the function M(t) is discontinuous.

However, a quick investigation of money-, economics-related formulae showed that no function depicts money's innate discreteness (jumping from dollar to next dollar, cent to next cent). Obviously a bank account jumps up or down in dollars/cents, hence, discreteness. But how would you construct such a function. Typically, a discrete function looks like this:

$$
 f(x) = \left\{ \begin{array}{r@{\quad \mathrm{if} \quad}l} 
 1  &  x \geq 0, \\
 \!\! -1  &  x < 0. \end{array} \right.
$$
that is, your classic step function. It seems to me a "money step function" would have to have a condition for literally every dollar -- or my thinking is way off here. So my question is, how can I depict the discrete nature of money jumping up and down by dollar/cent amounts over time?

Comment: Rather than a condition for every dollar, your conditions would be based on time-intervals (with a change every time the account balance changes), with the account balance constant over subintervals.  But yes, you would get a new piece of the function each time the balance changed.

Comment: If we avoid resorting to discrete time, I realize a function that came from the actual events of money going up or down could either show a smooth change over a time frame or a sudden jump, whereby the smooth change would be illusory. I'm also ruling out a "predictive," deterministic function, which $M(t)$ in the article might suggest and just considering a function derived from data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The jumps come in increments of time, not in increments of dollars.  You can use the floor or ceiling to describe the function.  Say I open a bank account for $100$ that pays $5$ simple interest every year.  Let $t$ be the time in years.  The account value is then $100+5\lfloor t \rfloor$.  You can also use the floor and ceiling to describe the effect of rounding.

Comment: So a function graph could show a slope, but it would be illusory, i.e., changing from $100.00 to $105.00 is a sudden occurrence, but to depict it in a graph as a smooth slope from y = 100 to y = 105 over t = 1 year would be a visual gimmick. You're resorting to difference equation and discrete time reasoning here, correct? I'm still thinking the function describing the actual plot would be like a conditional step function which had to have a separate condition clause for each jump. Or am I not getting something here?

Comment: No, the function graph would have a step at each integer.  It would be level at $100$ for $0 \le t \lt 1$, then level at $105$ for $1 \le t \lt 2$ and so on.  You could write it with condition clauses if you want, but would need one for each level.  The floor function takes care of all that.

Comment: The point of my question is to expose the confusion between continuous and discrete if we throw in a continuous-like concept of time. $M(t)$ looks like it could be a regular physics function where $t$ is a continuous entity, but econ formulae side-steps this. Continuously compounded interest looks like differential calculus, and its curve looks smooth, but it's an illusion, i.e., you can't take some $t$ and get something between, say, $1$ and $2$ cents, which is what the smooth graph is suggesting.

Comment: In physics, too, we consider the charge on a capacitor to be a continuous variable, but in fact it has to be a multiple of the electron charge.  As long as that granularity is too small to notice, we ignore it and consider the charge continuous and differentiable.  The granularity of money is the same.  For many purposes, it is too small to notice and we can ignore it.  For some purposes it is important and we can't resort to differentials.

Comment: Thanks for hanging with me. I'll look deeper into this issue. I'll check out capacitors.